# Sorting list of strings using L.sort with key multiple parameters

Tags: python

Pretty new to Python and have been playing around with lists and the sort member. My question is if I have a list of random strings (all strings of equal length):

```
li=["hgjtud", "iernfd", "scoeps", "stiiss", "stripe"]
```

and now I want to sort that list according to some rank which I define with the following function:

```
def rank_string(str1,str2):
    rank=0
    for i in range(len(str1)): #all strings will be checked to be equal length
        if (str1[i]==str2[i]):
            rank += 1
    return rank
```

and now I want to sort my list using this function together with a target string, so I try the following:

```
target_string="stripe"
df = lambda x:rank_string(x,target_string)
sorted_list = resultlist.sort(key=df)
```

I was of the impression that all list values will be given a key after one pass of the ranking function and thereafter be sorted according to this? This runs,  but sorted_list has value None. I assume then that being a n00b, I am missing something fundamental. What?  :-)

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.sort()` method sorts *in-place* and doesn't return anything.

Use [`sorted()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sorted) instead if you want the sorted list returned and the original input list left untouched.

```
>>> a = [2, 3, 1]
>>> a.sort()
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]
>>> b = [2, 3, 1]
>>> sorted(b)
[1, 2, 3]
>>> b
[2, 3, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

As other said, `sorted()` will return a new list. Your code could look like this:

```
li = ["hgjtud", "iernfd", "scoeps", "stiiss", "stripe"]
target_string = "stripe"

sorted_list = sorted(li, key=lambda x: sum(1 for c1,c2 in zip(x, target_string) if c1==c2))
```

returns `['hgjtud', 'iernfd', 'scoeps', 'stiiss', 'stripe']`

Comment: I'm beginning to realize that terseness is very pythonesque :-) and is the way to go. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Like the others said, use `sorted()`. Also you could make things shorter:

```
from functools import partial

def rank_string(str1, str2):
    return sum(a == b for a, b in zip(str1, str2))

li = ["hgjtud", "iernfd", "scoeps", "stiiss", "stripe"]
sorted_list = sorted(li, key=partial(rank_string, "stripe"))
```

[EDIT]

```
from operator import eq

def rank_string(str1, str2):
    return sum(map(eq, str1, str2))
```

:-)

[/EDIT]

Comment: again, I guess the terseness comes with the familiarity .-)

Answer (score 0):

`resultlist.sort` is a method of list, sorts resultlist in place, and returns `None`.

`sorted_list = sorted(li,  key=df)`
 should do the trick.